# .Net Core 5 API projects in docker containers not working with docker run or docker-compose - no errors

Tags: docker, asp.net-core-5.0

**What I am seeing:**

1. In VS2019, create a new .net core 5 web API app, turn off https (just to eliminate certificate issues for testing), call it dockertest.
2. Make NO changes to the app
3. Run it in docker from within VS  --  all works.
4. remove the dockertest docker container (not the image)
5. create container using `docker run -it --rm -p 7722:80 dockertest:dev`  -- the container runs with no errors and logs show it is listening on 80
6. Try access the app at http://localhost:7722/swagger/index.html -- ***returns ERROR no content***

**What else I have tried**

7. Manually build the image using : `docker build -t dockertest:0.0.1 -f ./dockertest/Dockerfile .`
8. create container using `docker run -it --rm -p 7722:80 dockertest:0.0.1`  -- the container runs with no errors and logs show it is listening on 80
9. Try access the app at http://localhost:7722/swagger/index.html -- ***returns 404 ERROR Not Found***
10. I have also tried creating the dockerfile in VSCode - same problem
11. I have tried using docker-compose file created by VSCode as well as manually created, same problems.

I suspect that this a network config error as the app appears to be running fine in the container, but port mappings are created so I'm kinda stuck now.

Any assistance pointing out the stupid mistake that I am making would be appreciated.

Many Thanks

Container Log:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]

      Now listening on: http://[::]:80

info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]

      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]

      Hosting environment: Production

info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]

      Content root path: /app
```

Container Inspect:

```
{
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "Args": [
        "dockertest3.dll"
    ],
    "Config": {
        "AttachStderr": true,
        "AttachStdin": true,
        "AttachStdout": true,
        "Cmd": null,
        "Domainname": "",
        "Entrypoint": [
            "dotnet",
            "dockertest3.dll"
        ],
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80",
            "DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true",
            "DOTNET_VERSION=5.0.1",
            "ASPNET_VERSION=5.0.1"
        ],
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "80/tcp": {}
        },
        "Hostname": "b4f5b2dff113",
        "Image": "dockertest3:0.0.5",
        "Labels": {},
        "OnBuild": null,
        "OpenStdin": true,
        "StdinOnce": true,
        "Tty": true,
        "User": "",
        "Volumes": null,
        "WorkingDir": "/app"
    },
    "Created": "2021-01-07T09:46:30.9864781Z",
    "Driver": "overlay2",
    "ExecIDs": null,
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Data": {
            "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/127d91088bf4c1723527366c1861d31374fae1d53981e40c148172d40d9a0d3d-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/yraxw6cr3174e5trbzalykc0s/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/nzvzpe3gdywqyblx27tbfklak/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/z3tx67lfy5810vtmibw4aqadk/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6a8a63e392362af66acc3482f595bca36ec76462cc3172fd51eeb4dda31af427/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9fc4fe532dedaec2ccffe78163f348904ba6e5c53d0f269567dc9ae4d78def58/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/41da0638d4d740b12bdb0d2d0ad4cfd2c42163b0d23e5a22b309eefbf86b68c1/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f0df011b8efda351f96981bdfa9f9fbc405132ee250a870cc2f69570792f65ff/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b3182380e8d22083de1e0b3468529a6b806f1569cf52589275c7e338ed717685/diff",
            "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/127d91088bf4c1723527366c1861d31374fae1d53981e40c148172d40d9a0d3d/merged",
            "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/127d91088bf4c1723527366c1861d31374fae1d53981e40c148172d40d9a0d3d/diff",
            "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/127d91088bf4c1723527366c1861d31374fae1d53981e40c148172d40d9a0d3d/work"
        },
        "Name": "overlay2"
    },
    "HostConfig": {
        "AutoRemove": true,
        "Binds": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "Capabilities": null,
        "Cgroup": "",
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "ConsoleSize": [
            11,
            302
        ],
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "CpuCount": 0,
        "CpuPercent": 0,
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
        "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
        "DeviceRequests": null,
        "Devices": [],
        "Dns": [],
        "DnsOptions": [],
        "DnsSearch": [],
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
        "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
        "IpcMode": "private",
        "Isolation": "",
        "KernelMemory": 0,
        "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
        "Links": null,
        "LogConfig": {
            "Config": {},
            "Type": "json-file"
        },
        "MaskedPaths": [
            "/proc/asound",
            "/proc/acpi",
            "/proc/kcore",
            "/proc/keys",
            "/proc/latency_stats",
            "/proc/timer_list",
            "/proc/timer_stats",
            "/proc/sched_debug",
            "/proc/scsi",
            "/sys/firmware"
        ],
        "Memory": 0,
        "MemoryReservation": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "MemorySwappiness": null,
        "NanoCpus": 0,
        "NetworkMode": "default",
        "OomKillDisable": false,
        "OomScoreAdj": 0,
        "PidMode": "",
        "PidsLimit": null,
        "PortBindings": {
            "80/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "7722"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Privileged": false,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "ReadonlyPaths": [
            "/proc/bus",
            "/proc/fs",
            "/proc/irq",
            "/proc/sys",
            "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
        ],
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0,
            "Name": "no"
        },
        "Runtime": "runc",
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "ShmSize": 67108864,
        "UTSMode": "",
        "Ulimits": null,
        "UsernsMode": "",
        "VolumeDriver": "",
        "VolumesFrom": null
    },
    "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/b4f5b2dff11316e2b310430a5ac013816bd02418f17fd1d902f9f55bddbe3b9e/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/b4f5b2dff11316e2b310430a5ac013816bd02418f17fd1d902f9f55bddbe3b9e/hosts",
    "Id": "b4f5b2dff11316e2b310430a5ac013816bd02418f17fd1d902f9f55bddbe3b9e",
    "Image": "sha256:eeadaeaa27801822b44a4f8a9fc6e2696a7f7d41cdd75f95fde6ad6e9170bcaf",
    "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/b4f5b2dff11316e2b310430a5ac013816bd02418f17fd1d902f9f55bddbe3b9e/b4f5b2dff11316e2b310430a5ac013816bd02418f17fd1d902f9f55bddbe3b9e-json.log",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "Mounts": [],
    "Name": "/interesting_lumiere",
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "EndpointID": "ff21dbc13c19bbd2792be6f4098a477c29d9f35b16c2277f84d0dfccccddd147",
        "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.5",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:05",
        "Networks": {
            "bridge": {
                "Aliases": null,
                "DriverOpts": null,
                "EndpointID": "ff21dbc13c19bbd2792be6f4098a477c29d9f35b16c2277f84d0dfccccddd147",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "IPAddress": "172.17.0.5",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "Links": null,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:05",
                "NetworkID": "c730b712c96204bf2d888a9371b9b4a54f056e864bcce689f6b71e80a98eb83a"
            }
        },
        "Ports": {
            "80/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "7722"
                }
            ]
        },
        "SandboxID": "a4897ddfc05c6ff3083ca1ee4c2e61d56e151a4d10edeca8ae22838a43f0279d",
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/a4897ddfc05c",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null
    },
    "Path": "dotnet",
    "Platform": "linux",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/b4f5b2dff11316e2b310430a5ac013816bd02418f17fd1d902f9f55bddbe3b9e/resolv.conf",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "State": {
        "Dead": false,
        "Error": "",
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Paused": false,
        "Pid": 23466,
        "Restarting": false,
        "Running": true,
        "StartedAt": "2021-01-07T09:46:31.2780767Z",
        "Status": "running"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to this, I have a partial answer.

This seems to have a lot to do with how VS2109 is customising the container for attaching to the debugger.

If I run a manual docker build and add the --no-cache parameter, the created docker containers work correctly, which is at least a step in the right direction.

For now I will work under the assumption that creating containers from within VS is a no no for production, although I cannot see that that is the intended functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I use Visual Studio for Docker Containers. I’ve found that Visual Studio 2019 is really buggy and therefore the only solution i’ve found is to run my applications as vanilla Visual Studio projects and write DockerCompose scripts to publish/create images separately from VS for now.